# Chrome error for font family: "Invalid property value"

Tags: css, google-chrome, hebrew

The following CSS works well on IE and FireFox, but chrome marks it as "Invalid property value" -

```
TD.desc1_hp { font-family: Arial,Arial (Hebrew),David (Hebrew);  }
```

any hint why?

Thanks,

Atara

Comment: Do you think `arial (hebrew)` will be present if `arial` is not?

Comment: Also, just to add to this, you cannot use `font-family: default;` either...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Font faces should be enclosed in double quotes. Font faces with parentheses seem to require that. This works:

```
TD.desc1_hp { font-family: Arial, "Arial (Hebrew)", "David (Hebrew)";  }
```

Comment: By the CSS 2.1 spec, “Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names.”

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This shows they _should_ be quoted as the alternative is to escape all punctuation. Thanks for the specs.